# Persistence strategy for high-performance proxy-like server application

Tags: .net, performance, caching, persistence

I'm designing a proxy-like server application using Microsoft .Net.
It handles messages arriving at very high frequency.
Each message references an in-memory entity which needs to be persisted to disk in order to recover from crashes.

```
message -> [Handler] -> message
              ^ |
              | |
              | v
         memory state
               |
               v
          disk state


Handler(Mesaage msg) {
  state = GetStateFromMemory(msg)
  Update(state)
  Persist(state)
}
```

I need to minimize the time spent in *Persist(state)*.

I tolerate a not-so-fast server startup if crash recovering.

What would be the best persistence strategy?

- IPC: MongoDB, Redis, SQLServer+ADO.Net, others?
- ... or non-IPC: BerkleyDb, raw binary files, others?
- *Persist(state)*: synchronous or asynchronous?

I'm considering delegating the actual persistence work to a background thread as follows:

```
Persist(State state) {
  AddToBlockingCollection(state)
}
void BackGroundThread() {
   state = ReadFromBlockingCollection()
   DoActualPersistence(state)
}
```

However, if *DoActualPersistence()* takes too long, the system can crash before the queue gets drained, producing inconsistency in the persisted state.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you considered an event store like geteventstore.com or maybe something simpler like persistent dictionary that uses esent under the hood

Comment: @Andrew, esent seems promising. Thanks!